# How to embed twitter video on website?

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, twitter

I want to embed twitter video on my webpage. I had followed twitter's developer page and get the embed code. But it is not displaying me anything. Then I try to write my iframe with video src then it shows CONTENT SECURITY POLICY issue that it will not allow the video to play other than twitter host. So, how to play their videos?

Refused to display [the link](https://twitter.com/WorldDanceVines/status/667057754738151424) in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Answer (score -1):

because those twitter account has been suspend 
(please check https://twitter.com/WorldDanceVines )

and the suspended its cause of the video disallow by twitter policy
you can check it on here https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169350

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Instead of just posting links, please elaborate what could be the possible solution to it.